# Force Drupal to merge and compress css

Tags: css, drupal, optimization

I'm working on a Drupal site. When I test in IE8 and IE9 the css don't load on my local server. When the site is deployed everything is fine. I need to be able to test on my local server to fix any issue I might encounter before pushing the site live.

I guess it is because this site is over IE's limit in http requests. Is there a way to force Drupal to optimise the css even in development mode.

When I go to the admin/performance menu, I can't select the optimise css option.

Comment: What does your htacess look like? You may have some restrictions in there

Comment: I don't know anything about htaccess. What am i supposed to look for? :(

Comment: Is your site http://www.vehicletrackingprices.co.uk or  http://quotes.expertsinmoney.com? Is it http or https?

Comment: I think I will have to ask the devs in charge of the site.  I had to make a copy of an existing site which is neither of those. and this will be a new url as well. Otherwise it's http.

Answer (score 0):

Did you "borrow" this htaccess from another site? Reason I ask is because you said you are not using this htaccess for neither  vehicletrackingprices.co.uk or quotes.expertsinmoney.com but strangely enough you have a 301 re-direct for quotes.expertsinmoney.com and an index request for vehicletrackingprices.co.uk. :/

Could they be the cause of your problem? If we're lucky, they are. Am I sure? No. But either way those two items deserve atttention.

On the other hand, I tested your htaccess against your 301 so that I can see if it has a ny errors your server may be fighting with and I did find the following:

[image]

Comment: I didn't borrow it from anybody, I'm "innocent" :) it's on the site I'm working on. It might not be the live one though. I'll check with the devs in charge today. Thanks for your effort :) much appreciated